# How to add labels when using matplotlib to draw histagrams?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I draw two separate histograms, but I don't know how to add the x labels and y labels and the tile separately for each graph.
Here is my code:

```
subdata1=dataFrame.loc[:,['Column1','Column2']]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(6,4), dpi=100, sharey=False, tight_layout=True)
axs[0].hist(subdata1.Column1, density=True, bins=8) #1st graph
axs[1].hist(subdata1.Column2, density=True, bins=8) #2nd graph
```

Comment: Do you mean `ax[0].set_xlabel("my xlabel")` and `ax[0].set_title("my title")`?  If not, please explain into more detail what is asked for. Also, it might be helpful to add some reproducible test data for the two columns.

Comment: thank you! that helps